# How to check if any character in a list is contained in a string

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to check if a users input contains any special characters from a list, does anyone know who I would go about doing this?

I've tried the LIKE operator:

```
 Dim sMatch As Boolean = tTitle.Text Like "[-/\,.:;*?""""<>|&'[]^%£$()_+=!#]"
```

but doesn't seem to work, i think special characters are used for settings.

Is there a RegEx i could use for this??

Thanks for any help.

J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx) and [ToCharArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) will help here

```
Dim sMatch As Boolean = tTitle.Text.IndexOfAny("-/\,.:;*?""""<>|&'[]^%£$()_+=!#".ToCharArray) > -1
```

edit: Some of those characters have to be wrapped in their own square brackets for the like to work, plus you'd need some *'s around the [], and you'd have trouble square bracketing the ] itself - [Like Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The regex alternative would be:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tTitle.Text, "[\-/\\,.:;*?""<>|&'[\]\^%£$()_+=!#]")
```